# How to create an object that correspond to the inverse (-1x) of the daily performance of an asset in R?

Tags: r

The objective is to create a tracker that seek a return that is -1x the return of Bitcoin in order to simulate BTC/USD short position in a portoflio.

For example I would like the `btcInv` object goes up +3.96% after price of Bitcoin felt on 05-feb, then loses -1.42% after price rise on 06-feb.

```
Date    Dernier     Ouv.    + Haut  + Bas   Variation %
06/02/2015  218.80  215.73  223.00  213.16  1.42%
05/02/2015  215.73  224.62  225.00  212.00  -3.96%
```

The code bellow return a line that oscillate around 100 but it doesn't do the job because `btcInv` always equals to 100.

What would be a proper way to minus the daily return to the previous `BtcInv` value (i.e. the day n-1 value) ?

```
btcInv <- 100

# Use tryCatch() in case we try to get data too far in the past that 
# Oanda doesn't provide. Return NULL if there is an error, and Filter
# to only include data that has at least 1 row.
btc <- do.call(rbind, Filter(NROW, lapply(0:5, function(i) {
  tryCatch(getFX("BTC/USD", 
                 from = Sys.Date() -499 * (i + 1),
                 to = Sys.Date() - 499 * i,
                 env=NULL), error=function(e) NULL)
})))

btcInv <- btcInv - (dailyReturn(btc) * 100)
```

Thank you

Comment: It would be easier to help if you had a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output. As far as I can tell your programming question doesn't have anything to do with bitcoin specifically. Maybe you're just looking for the `diff()` function?

Comment: To give more precision to my question I will add an example.

Comment: I'm not sure the diff() function will help. I hope the description of the question is better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With arithmetic returns, you can multiply the first price by `cumprod(1+r)` to recreate the series.  If you want the inverse, you can use `-r`.  i.e. `cumprod(1-r)`

```
# sample data
btc <- getFX("BTC/USD", from="2015-02-01", to="2015-02-10", auto.assign=FALSE)
btcInv <- cumprod(1-dailyReturn(btc)) * as.numeric(btc[1])
all.equal(dailyReturn(btc), -dailyReturn(btcInv))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: If you want an index that starts at 100, you can replace `as.numeric(btc[1])` with `100`

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you very much for your help GSee.